# memcpy with offset to struct in swift

Tags: swift, struct, bluetooth, memcpy

I'm receiving bluetooth data for a packed struct splitted over 3 packets, where first byte of each packet is a number of this packet and the rest is data. I'm using next code to assembly the stuct :

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
       guard let value = characteristic.value as NSData? else { return }

       var packetNumber = UInt8()
       let maxPacketSize = 17

       value.getBytes(&packetNumber, length: 1)

       memcpy(&settings + maxPacketSize * (Int(packetNumber) - 1), value.bytes + 1, value.length - 1)
}
```

It works well with first packet,  but second and third packets are not copied to the struct, it remains filled by zeros. Same approach in objc works well with all 3 packets. What is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I was able to find code that works:

```
        let destination: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = &settings + maxPacketSize * (Int(packetNumber) - 1)
        memcpy(destination, value.bytes + 1, value.length - 1)
```

Looks like without explicit declaration of UnsafeMutableRawPointer it created just UnsafeRawPointer. Interesting that it was only in a case of added offset.